# How to make android XML or Kotlin button take me to my other activity in XML?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio, kotlin

I don't have a java file for some reason. i have a "Main Activity" in Kotlin. Hence i was wondering if i would be able to add a button which on click takes me to my other activity?

heres the main activity code :

```
import android.content.Intent
import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat.startActivity


class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.main)
    } }
```

here's the other activity i made which should open the pg activity :

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle

class pg1 : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.pg1)
    } }
```

the files i have :
layout\main.xml and layout\pg1.xml

MainActivity is a kotlin clss and pg1 is a kotlin file

Comment: Did you even try to search for answer? this si the very first tutorial on android developer page....

Comment: I did :) however they were all for the java files and I tried them but they didn't work. I started using android studio yesterday and this was my last resort.

Comment: There is a button, where you can switch from Java to Kotlin, but if you did not see that, you'll have a hard time learning.

Comment: I'm on a 720p screen and a burnt out cpu and gpu, it's already hard using it with those specs. Even using Chrome takes time. Plus my mouse's lmb is damaged so I'm unable to do shit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create second activity which will be opened on button click

**Here's how you can do in coding**

```
    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
      button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
         @Override
         public void onClick(View v) {
            openNewActivity();
         }
      });
   
   public void openNewActivity(){
      Intent intent = new Intent(this, NewActivity.class);
      startActivity(intent);
   }
```

Comment: hello i've edited my post , would you be able to tell me where and how to place this?

Comment: In your MainActivity.kt file

Answer (score 0):

Add a button first to your main.xml, then give it an id like "switch_scene"..
Then go to your main activity and type the code
Am assuming you have kotlin extension enabled.. that allows you to reference IDs from xml directly..
.

```
  switch_scene.addOnClickListener{
     val newIntent= Intent(this, pg1::class.java)
     startActivity (newIntent)
 }
```

Forgive me if I made mistakes.. am coding with my phone you see as I am not at home.